# Spring WS not accepting basic auth credentials

Tags: spring-boot, basic-authentication, spring-ws

I've been struggling with this one for a while and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm supposed to add basic authentication to my SOAP web service in Spring. I made the security config pretty simple (maybe too simple) so it concentrates on basic auth only (see below).

When I'm accessing the base URL from the browser, the authentication seems to be working, it asks for the credentials and if I provide them correctly, it accepts them.

However, when I want to send the SOAP request that contains the basic auth header to my web service endpoint, Spring Security sends back 401 to me. I tried sending the request with SOAPUI, Postman and from Windows Powershell via Invoke-WebRequest, and the result is the same whereas if I catch the request with Wireshark, the right header is there.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.8 for this project (same version with Spring Web Services and Security).

The security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("foo")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("bar"))
            .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

To my understanding, there is nothing specific I have to add to the **web service config** itself so all related basic auth settings can be done in the **security config** class. Or am I wrong?

Appreciate your help.

**Update**

Here is the request/response pair:

REQUEST:

```
POST /foo/endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://foo.bar"
Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==
Content-Length: 9688
Host: localhost:1502
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:foo="http://foobar.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
   // body omitted
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 401 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 14:22:29 GMT
```

Comment: In browser console do you have only 401 error? Or something else like CORS policy? And can you add screens with xml and headers which you try send by postman?

Comment: I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

**configure(HttpSecurity http)** needs some modifications to enable the http basic authentication in your code.

**authorizeRequests()** is used for authorization purposes. Once after a user successfully logged in, what all the resources(endpoints) should be accessible to logged-in user, is defined by **authorizeRequests()**. I also recommend, while authorizing the endpoints, you better use the **antMatchers**. For Example: I have modified the above code as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("foo")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("bar"))
            .roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/simple/**").hasRole("USER");
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
} 
}
```

I hope this would work for you. Try & let me know.

NOTE: In Spring boot, just by adding the spring-boot-starter-security dependency, security gets enabled, without any configurations. So now, you trying to re-configure the basic auto-configuration. By extending, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. That's correct.

POSTMAN: use authorization header
[image: BASIC AUTH IN POSTMAN]

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I modify my config accordingly (replacing "/simple/**" by my endpoint path), I get 403 from the server. :)

Comment: That means, you are authenticated successfully. Only authorization is failing. If possible, can you post the controller code.